# r sqldf select statement not working as expected

Tags: r, twitter, sqldf

I am trying to use sqldf to create a data frame which is a subset of an original data frame.

tweets.df is a data frame consisting of 19 variables. One of the variables is called location.

A sample of the data can be seen below.

```
 tweets.df$location
 [1] ""                              ""                         "Brooklyn, NY"                    
 [4] ""                              ""                         ""                                
 [7] "Brooklyn, NY"                  "Hope Eternal"             "Boston, MA"
```

Trying to run a sql statement yields the following

```
sqldf("select * from 'tweets.df' where  'tweets.df$location' like '%Brook%'")
[1] text  favorited  favoriteCount   replyToSN   created  truncated   replyToSID     
[8] id    replyToUID statusSource    screenName  retweetCount  isRetweet    retweeted      
[15] longitude  latitude    location    language   profileImageURL
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Running sqldf("select * from 'tweets.df'") returned the entire data frame.

What is wrong with me select statement that includes the LIKE clause whereby it does not return any rows?

Comment: Without sqldf: `tweets.df[ grepl("Brooklyn", tweets.df$location), ]`

Comment: Read [mcve] on how to ask a question. In particulr you need to provide a minimal version of your input in reproducible form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
sqldf("select * from 'tweets.df' where  location like '%Brook%'")

#location
#1 Brooklyn, NY
#2 Brooklyn, NY
```

In SQL, it already knows that `location` is part of `tweets.df`, so there's no need to redo that with `tweets.df$location`.

Answer (score 1):

The right code is the following

```
sqldf('select * from tweets.df where location ="%Brook%"')
```

Try this code, It should work!

Comment: Sorry but tweets.df is an object dataframe?
Have you created the dataframe tweets.df or is a dataset already contained in R?

Comment: I created the dataframe. Mike's answer resolves my issue.